# how to assert if an element is not present on ruby cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am using cucumber to create some automations on ruby and I have to verify that a certain button with a specific id does not exist.

How can I do it?

Comment: You will need to provide more information about how/what you are automating. For example, are you trying to automate a web application or a native application? If automating a web application, what gem are you using to drive the browser (eg Capybara, Selenium, Watir).

Comment: Automating a web application using selenium and watir

Comment: If you are using Selenium/Watir, why accept a Capybara answer?

Comment: thought to change gems, checked online about capybara and capybara sounds more user friendly. tried this sol on a different env and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using cucumber ruby, I assume you're probably using capybara. You can use one of the built-in matchers in one of your step definitions like this:

```
page.has_no_button?("buttonId")
```

You can find this matcher in the [git repo of capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/304e2fbfe1e54702eb65f2a3feda1c7b9b99ff36/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb#L262) along with all the other available matchers.

It uses the `has_no_selector?` matcher that you can use to check wether any element is present on the page. You'll find it's [documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/304e2fbfe1e54702eb65f2a3feda1c7b9b99ff36/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb#L52) in the code as well.